# SSIS package executed in Server agent doesn't do its work (even while reporting success)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have to say that I hate myself for such general question as "What I am doing wrong?" but I simply have no idea what can be the problem:

I've created SSIS package that takes the data from flat files (CSV), counts the average on one of the columns, groups by date and writes it to the database and deletes the original file. All works fine when executed within SSIS, but when I am scheduling it within Server Agent it simply doesn't work - log reports success but there is no new data in the database and the .csv file exists in its original location.
I know the problem with protection level set up in SSIS, so I've changed it to "EncryptAllWithPassword" and I use the same password with Server Agent.
[Here is a link to the Server Agent Job script](http://textuploader.com/o5qt) (created as "script job as DROP and CREATE")

Edit: Just to make things weirder, using

```
  dtexcec /f {filepath} /de {password}
```

executes program without problem. I know I can shedule such command in the Windows itself, but i'd like to keep all scheduled jobs in one place - in the Server Agent

EDIT: Solved by changing the path to UNC

Comment: first, does the account that execute the package have file system acces to the location of the package? second, how is the package set up to deal with errors and unexpected results?

Comment: Are you sure the package isn't pointed to another database (e.g. development)?

Comment: Go through your package and on every object, set FailPackageOnFailure=True and FailParentOnFailure=True.   Then run it again from the job and see if the job still reports success.

Comment: @BenThul is probably correct.  Check that your connection managers are configured to point to the location that you expect.  The package is probably indeed succeeding, but writing to your localmachine or a development location.

Comment: As a general SSIS reminder, UNC paths at all times and ensure that the job is executed by a proxy account with appropriate permissions.  Anything else leads to unpredictable results.

Comment: 1. account has access to the file location
2. The package is pointing to the database on the same server that the Server Agent is running. When I run this package on SSIS data is written to the correct database
3. I can't really set "FailPackage on Failure" because I do expect that some files might be corrupted - I have a proper error handling in the package. But then I am testing with the proper data and results differ when ran in SSIS and via Agent

Comment: I deleted my community wiki answer, as I see that @EricHauenstein might have been the one to put you on the right track. If so, he should probably promote his comment to an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: If UNC was the answer you should've seen the error in the SSIS logs. You might want to learn how to do that to save yourself further difficulties.

Answer (score 3):

There are two important things to remember when setting up packages to run via a SQL Server Agent job.

Use UNC paths for all file locations, no matter how simple.  There is a high probability that the server will have a different view of the file structure than your development machine, so UNC paths ensure that both machines are referencing the same paths.

Use a proxy account to execute that package, as described here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/.
The proxy account must have access to the physical paths and the server objects.
This also allows for security stratification on your various packages (not all packages need access to everything).