# SSIS 2012 for each loop finds no files after deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working on a package to import files and then move them to a completed\rejected folder. In the Data Tools everything is working fine when I start debugging, but when I deploy it to the SQL Server the For Each Loop container finds no files.

I've created a package almost identical to this one over a year ago that is and has been up and running. I've created a package that contains only a rename file task inside of a for each loop. Like before, it works flawlessly in from data tools, but fails to find the text files when it's run from SQL Server.

(Yes, I am moving the files back to the starting position after running the package)

Comment: Can you post the relevant code/script?

Comment: Different permissions to the folders?  I think when you run in VS it uses your credentials, but when you run in SQL Server it will be running with the SQL Server service's credentials.  Another thing to consider related to this is mapped drives.

Comment: Are you using UNC paths and a proxy account? See my previous answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25665702/2587452