# SSIS package runs well when executed manually, but fails when executed as a Job

Tags: ssis, package, jobs

As the title says - if I execute the package manually in SSIS it works perfectly, but if it runs as a Job it fails.

Package contains few simple blocks (creating new folder, moving file from one folder to another) and for each loop container. In this container there is a script, which pastes formulas, sorts tables, deletes rows etc. in Excel files.

It is possible that those Excel files do not close properly, but I don't think that this is the case here.

For about 80 excel files, job opens only a half of them (most times, sometimes more sometimes less) and then stops. There are really a lot of jobs on this server and its the first issue like that. Whats the problem?

Comment: What error is issued when the job fails?

Comment: You need to paste the error. Proberbly its access to your folders thats the problem. Give the SQL Job service agent the proper rights to your folder path

Comment: I guess they are permission issue to the folders, try executing in windows scheduler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665702/2587452 - This may help.

Comment: Sorry for not aswering for a long time. When the job fails, error says that its a Script Task fault - so something is wrong with this excel closing. I used UNC paths and use a proxy account to run the package.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem , we have faced:

Here , what we have done:
Say Package "ABC" has stopped executing in job scheduler.

1. We have created a new blank SSIS package.
2. Copy N Pasted all the task and connections from old one.
3. Rename the new SSIS as "ABC" after taking backup of old "ABC"

and problem was solved.

Some problems, needs non-logic solutions and this is one of them. ;-)